# iOS + DayLight Saving time missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I face an issue after converting `UTC` time to local TimeZone (in my case `DTS`), its missing one hour.

Function to convert `UTC` time to local time:

```
+ (NSString *) convertUTCTimeToLocalTime:(NSString *)dateString {
    @try {

        //Log: dateString - 2016-03-08 06:00:00 // Time in UTC
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

        NSTimeZone *gmtTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
        //Log: gmtTimeZone - GMT (GMT) offset 0

        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmtTimeZone];
        NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
        //Log: dateFromString - 2016-03-08 06:00:00 +0000

        [NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
        NSTimeZone * sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        //Log: sourceTimeZone - America/New_York (EDT) offset -14400 (Daylight)

        // Add daylight time
        BOOL isDayLightSavingTime = [sourceTimeZone isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:dateFromString];
        if (isDayLightSavingTime) {
            NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [sourceTimeZone  daylightSavingTimeOffsetForDate:dateFromString];
            dateFromString = [dateFromString dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeInterval];
        }

        [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:sourceTimeZone];

        NSString *dateRepresentation = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
        //Log: dateRepresentation - 2016-03-08 01:00:00

        return dateRepresentation;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception :%@", exception.debugDescription);
        return nil;
    }
}
```

In above code `//Log:` shows debug values for define variables.

I also check for `isDayLightSavingTime` but it never executes. (always returns `NO`).

Also I can not set hardcore timeZone as `DST` in code, because application may have different time zones.

Not able to figure out how to deal with missing one hour.

Last line: `dateRepresentation` shows time `1 AM` which is wrong. It should be `2 AM`.

Comment: Give an example of a string that you are passing to this method.

Comment: @TomHarrington I have written example string in code - `2016-03-08 06:00:00`